# qliksense - connection to remote server

Tags: javascript, qlikview, qliksense

I have a remote server with qliksense. I want to get connect to that server so I could receive json data from it.
The connection should be done using javascript.
connecting to qliksense desktop on port 4848 is successful.

How can I connect to a remote machine?

what is the right code to do it?

Local working connection:

```
var config = {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: '4848',
        isSecure: window.location.protocol === "https:"



    qsocks.Connect(config).then(global => {
        return global.openDoc('Ori_Test.qvf')
    })
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure you can do that with sense server without building a custom extension - ...If you can't find it in the docs then it's not a server functionality. API docs: http://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/September2017/Content/APIs-and-SDKs.htm

Comment: I found this, maybe this will help you: http://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/September2017/Subsystems/EngineAPI/Content/introducing-engine-API.htm they show how to connect to the server...